# draggable & resizable Div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wrote my own draggable & resizable code,

```
var startX, startY, startWidth, startHeight;
var div = document.getElementById('div'),
    x1 = 0,
    y1 = 0,
    x2 = 0,
    y2 = 0;

var element;

function reCalc() {
    var x3 = Math.min(x1, x2);
    var x4 = Math.max(x1, x2);
    var y3 = Math.min(y1, y2);
    var y4 = Math.max(y1, y2);

    div.style.left = x3 + 'px';
    div.style.top = y3 + 'px';
    div.style.width = x4 - x3 + 'px';
    div.style.height = y4 - y3 + 'px';
}
$(document).on("mousedown", function (e) {

    var target = $(event.target);

    x1 = e.clientX;
    y1 = e.clientY;

    if (element && element.find('.resizer').is(target)) {
        return;
    }

    if (element) {
        element.remove();
    }

    div.hidden = 0;
    x1 = e.clientX;
    y1 = e.clientY;
    reCalc();
});

$(document).on("mousemove", function (e) {
    x2 = e.clientX;
    y2 = e.clientY;
    reCalc();
});

$(document).on("mouseup", function (e) {

    div.hidden = 1;

    var target = $(event.target);

    if (element && element.find('.resizer').is(target)) {
        return;
    }

    element = $("<div>");
    element[0].style.left = div.style.left;
    element[0].style.top = div.style.top;
    element[0].style.width = div.style.width;
    element[0].style.height = div.style.height;


    var resizer = document.createElement('div');
    resizer.className = 'resizer';
    element.append(resizer);
    resizer.addEventListener('mousedown', initDrag, false);

    $("body").append(element.show());

    element.on("mousedown", function () {
        event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    });

    element.on("mouseup", function () {  
        event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    });
});



function initDrag(e) {
    startX = e.clientX;
    startY = e.clientY;
    startWidth = parseInt(document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(element[0]).width, 10);
    startHeight = parseInt(document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(element[0]).height, 10);
    document.documentElement.addEventListener('mousemove', doDrag, false);
    document.documentElement.addEventListener('mouseup', stopDrag, false);
}

function doDrag(e) {
    element[0].style.width = (startWidth + e.clientX - startX) + 'px';
    element[0].style.height = (startHeight + e.clientY - startY) + 'px';
}

function stopDrag(e) {
    document.documentElement.removeEventListener('mousemove', doDrag, false);
    document.documentElement.removeEventListener('mouseup', stopDrag, false);
}
```

but when I resize, It does not handle mousedown event properly. It should stop drag when i mouse up

Any solution??

http://jsfiddle.net/Dipak1991/7d8f65b8/1/

Comment: seems yours jsfiddle is not working

Comment: Nope for me its giving errors..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no listener to invoke your `stopDrag()` function:

```
resizer.addEventListener('mousedown', initDrag, false);

// Add
resizer.addEventListener('mouseup', stopDrag, false);
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/7d8f65b8/2/)

Comment: Ohhh...god ...such a foooool I am